# Navigating Through an Array Of Elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my code, I'm trying to navigate through an array of strings. I'm also using observable and I try to map it through next and previous buttons. I can see the first element of the array on the input field but I want to navigate to the next elements and see them in the input field using next button. My code is below, how can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="input" value="{{ slider$ | async }}" />
  {{ slider$ | async }}
</div>

<div>
  <button mat-button (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  slides: string[] = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4'];
  slider$: Observable<any> = of(this.slides).pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    map((arr: string[]) => {
      return arr[0];
    }),
    tap(console.log)
  );



  previous() {
    this.slider$.pipe(
      map((arr: string[]) => {
        return arr[0];
      }),
      tap(console.log)
    );
  }

  next() {
    this.slider$.pipe(
      map((arr: string[]) => {
        return arr[1];
      }),
      tap(console.log)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `subscribe` only once to `slider$`. You could navigate through the array like so:

**template HTML**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="current$ | async as current">
  <input type="input" [value]="current" />  <!-- use property binding -->
  <p>{{ current }}</p>
</ng-container>

<div>
  <button mat-button (click)="navigate(false)">Previous</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="navigate(true)">Next</button>
</div>
```

**component**

```js
@Component({...})
export class TheComponent {  
  index = 0;
  slides: string[] = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4'];
  slider$ = of(this.slides)
  current$!: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.current$ = this.slider$.pipe(map(arr => arr[this.index]));
  }

  navigate(add: boolean): void {
    this.index = add ? ++this.index : --this.index;
    console.log('index', this.index)
    this.current$ = this.slider$.pipe(map(arr => arr[this.index]));
  }
}
```